# middle school vs high school

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a seperate term for Middle School & High School? I use [Glosbe](https://www.glosbe.com/en/eo) primarily for word translations, because it also gives sample sentences. It translates both terms as mezlernejo. Google translate gives mezlernejo for high school, & meza lernejo for middle school.

Comment: What do you mean by "middle school" and "high school"? Due to different education systems and different naming conventions, these terms have vastly different meanings in different English-speaking countries, let alone non-English-speaking countries that more or less literally translated their local school names into English.

Comment: I realize not all countries use the same terms. How about "junior high"? There's gotta be some way to distinguish them for those that use those terms as opposed to just primary & secondary.

Answer (score 2):

As Das-g pointed out, the school systems are vastly different. A general scheme is

- *infanĝardeno* : kindergarten, pre-school
- *baza/elementa lernejo* : elementary school, main focus on teaching reading and writing
- *mezlernejo* : middle level school, main focus on subjects
- *altlernejo* : high level school which can be *universitato* or *faka altlernejo*, vocational university

Of course you can add describing terms such as *politeknika, humanisma, scienca* to any of them if needed. Since these terms are commonly understood you can use them to explain your local school system.

Comment: I changed the scheme to match one given in https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lernejo.

Answer (score 0):

La respondo estas *ne*. Pro la kialoj menciitaj en la komentoj kaj demandoj. Tamen en familia uzo oni devas povi nomi tiujn malsamajn lernejojn.

Ni uzas jenan proksimuman laŭaĝan apartigon, kiu parte spegulas la landan (mi suspektas ke ĉiuj faras ion tian: klopodi speguli siajn eduksistemojn.

- lernejo (ekde 4 ĝis 11, kun nur unu aŭ tre malmultaj instruistoj en ĉiu klaso, kutime en la sama klasĉambro, sen elekteblaj fakoj)
- liceo (inter 12 kaj 18, tiom da instruistoj kiom da fakoj, kelkaj elekteblaj por la plej aĝaj)
- universitato (pli ol 18)

Comment: @das-g Jes, la vorto estas nur *liceo*, mi nur klarigis ke ĝi apartenas al la Unua Oficialigo. Mi volis tion montri same kiel vortaroj (eble malsukcese :))

Comment: @das-g okej, mi ne pensis ke tio tiel povus ĝeni. PIV (Plena Ilustrita Vortaro de Esperanto) aperigas tion apud ĉiu tia radiko, sed vi pravas, eble iu partoprenanto ne scias pri Fundamentaj kaj oficialaj radikoj. Mi forigis la mencion.